# Codeception continue even if something fails

Tags: javascript, webdriver, codeception

I have a Codeception script that I use to simulate user behaviour, is there a way to run the script and ignore the errors?

By the way, I am using acceptance testing and WebDriver to enable JavaScript simulations.

Comment: The whole point of testing is that you don't ignore errors. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: The point is to simulate user activity to test how many users the server can serve.

Comment: Use a proper load testing tool like JMeter or Gatling for that purpose.